# Friendly URL works partially when a rewrite rule is applied

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a problem with the .htaccess when I apply a rewrite rule. Below I explain what I did:

In localhost:

Path: **/dev/Site**

desired Friendly URL:  **www.site.com/l/p**   -> **l** is for language and **p** is for page

The source url is: **www.site.com/index.php?p=about&l=en**

in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$2&l=$1 [L]
```

The situation is the rewrite rule works partially

1- www.site.com/en/about works but when the img folder located inside for e.g **/dev/Site/template/ing** failed to get the file because the following structure is sought: **http://127.0.0.1/dev/Site/en/templates/img/**

---

HTML ( eg: )

```
<h1 class='center'>
  <a href='http://www.Site1.com/index.php?p=about&l=dev/Site1/es' >
    <img src='**templates/img/logo.png**' width='204' height='40' alt='Site1 Logo' /></a>
</h1>
```

I've found that the rewrite rule apply the change in the url of the href..

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and where is `index.php` located?

Comment: At the beginning of the test I put the file on the root of the site and then I moved to the root of the localhost but didn't work

Comment: Aren't root of the site and root of the localhost same?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a couple reason i found out in your piece of code,
your code currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$2&l=$1 [L]
```

but what i believe your code should be is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?p=$2&l=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

The changes i made are:

- Changed `+` to `*` (the `+` means one or more, while the `*` means zero or more, if you are looking for the img path then you dont have both the variables from your htaccess)
- added the `QSA` in the rule (this makes the query string append, so basicly you are adding the strings to the GET i believe?)
- changed the `[^/]` to `.` (the dot means any character should do precisely what you want)
- set the base for the rewriterule to root(`/dev/Site`)

I hope that i have helped you out and i should advise you to do some research on htaccess.

---

Edit 1:

try to change the image including like this:

```
<h1 class='center'>
  <a href='http://www.Site1.com/index.php?p=about&l=dev/Site1/es' >
    <img src='/templates/img/logo.png' width='204' height='40' alt='Site1 Logo' /></a>
</h1>
```

---

The change:

- Changed the loading of the image from `template/img/logo.png` to `/template/img/logo.png` (your way of including (without the `/` before the path) tells the server that it has to load from the url, using the backslash you tell to look starting in the root).

Comment: Same result... for e.g   I found that when I enter  http://127.0.0.1/dev/Site1/en/about... if I check the source of the image in the website... the url is http://127.0.0.1/dev/Site1/en/img/brand.jpg so... the problem is in the htaccess file or the internal structure of the website that I need to modify?

Comment: could you edit your question and add the html so i could see how you try to include the image?

Comment: I added an example above

Comment: but take a look of the url rewritten in the <a>, why is it replated in that way? should be displayed like this:  <a href='http://www.Site1.com/es/about' >